# How do I separate DOM view logic from DOM event (controller?) logic in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am not sure if I am separating my application into MVC logic correctly. I am confused as to how to deal with the DOM, which deals with both view and event logic. For example:

```
var HistoryView = function($siblingEl) {
  this.$el = $(
    '<div class="history">' +
      '<button class="backward"><</button>' +
      '<button class="forward">></button>' +
    '</div>'
  );
  $siblingEl.after( this.$el );
  $('.backward').on('click', function() {
    Events.fire('clickPrev');
  });

  ...
```

And then a controller:

```
 var HistoryManager = function(board, game) {
   Events.on('clickPrev', function() {
     var move = History.getPrev();
     if (move) {
       board.undoMove(move);
       game.turn -= 1;
       History.undo();
     }
   });

   ...
```

A good chunk of my view's code is dedicated to listening to DOM events and then passing them to my custom `Event` metaobject; my controller then listens to `Event` rather than the DOM. It seems a lot more straightforward to have the controller listen to the DOM directly, but then it would have to know about the view. Is there a way of dealing with this? In Backbone, it seems like the view just gets smarter (becomes a View-Controller). What are some other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good comparison between different ways to implement an MV* pattern I found Todo MVC really useful http://todomvc.com/. I use Google closure, and my preference is also to merge the controller and view into one. However, with closure you could separate them out, by having the view create the HTML and implementing an interface for view objects that a controller might need. See goog.ui.Control and goog.ui.ControlRenderer for an example. In your case, the view would provide methods such as `getBackButton()` and `getForwardButton()`. The controller would then listen to the DOM events rather than custom view events.

However, other people think a View should listen to DOM events and a controller should listen to view events (as in your example). I don't think there's one correct way of doing things. What matters most is that you can easily (unit) test your code ;)